# How can I get the latest date from two columns in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have a table look like this:

```
ID   B     C      date01        date02
11  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-02
11  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-03
11  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-01
11  xxx   xxxx   2020-02-03    2020-02-08
11  xxx   xxxx   2020-02-03    2020-02-31
22  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-02
22  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-03
22  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-01
22  xxx   xxxx   2020-02-03    2020-02-08
22  xxx   xxxx   2020-02-03    2020-02-31
```

I want to return everything but with a latest date of date01 & date02 for each ID, expected output:

```
11  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-03
22  xxx   xxxx   2020-05-01    2020-05-03
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, B, C, date01, date02
FROM 
    table
order by date01 desc
GROUP BY ID
```

but it gave me: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax`

i'm very new to SQL and still learning, What I did wrong? Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Update: I forgot a constraint, some `date01` is later than `date02`, I only want the date where `date01` is earlier than `date02`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "aggregate" by `id`. You can use `MAX()` to get the latest dates, as in:

```
select
  id, 
  max(b),
  max(c),
  max(date01),
  max(date02)
from t
group by id
```

Comment: This works, but will also return the record where ```date01``` is later than 'date02', how can I only return the date where ```date01``` is earlier than 'date02'?

Comment: should be able to just add `where date01 < date02`, which will ignore any rows where date01 is equal to or after date02

Comment: Hi @JStephen It didn't work, I still got a record where ```date01 = 2016/3/30``` and ```date02=2016/1/15```, and the column name were changed to ```max(date01``` and ```max(date02)```.

Comment: That's weird, are your columns DATE type? also, `where date01 < date02` will filter out those rows before getting the max of each, if you need to ignore the resulting rows after max is calculated you could use `having max(date01) < max(date02)` after your `group by` clause. Though in this case the where statement should be enough. Keep in mind that the values for max(date01) and max(date02) could come from different rows.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where greatest(t.date1, t.date2) = (select max(greatest(t1.date1, t2.date2))
                                    from t t2
                                    where t2.id = t.id
                                   );
```

Another alternative is window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by greatest(t1.date1, t2.date2) desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, I would use analytic functions here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, MAX(date01) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) max_date01,
        MAX(date02) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) max_date02
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE date01 = max_date01 AND date02 = max_date02;
```

Comment: For some reason, I can only use MySQL workbench 6.3 CE